# access vba requery oddness

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

It's been awhile since i've worked in VBA.  I have a bound form.  It has two drop down lists.  One list is bound the other not (the first ddl is a list of values.  The second gets refreshed when the first one changes, using the value of the first to create a query for the second.  That value is used as a fk in the table the form is bound too).

Anyway, when the form is first run and uses the default value for ddl 1, if the second combobox is empty, and I try to get the value, it's null, which is what you would expect.  But, I have code that runs when ddl1's value changes, to requery ddl2.  When it requeries, if the list is empty, and I do combobox1.value, instead of being null, the value is 1.  This is confusing, because, since the list is empty, I would think it should be null.  What's going on here?  Here is what I have:

Combo1 is bound to a table
Combo 2 uses this query:

```
SELECT tbl_office.id, tbl_office.office_name
FROM tbl_office
WHERE (((tbl_office.otherTable_id)=[Forms]![dlg_addDivision].[Combo1]));
```

On Combo1 afterUpdate event:

```
  me.Combo2.requery
```

So, after combo1 afterUpdate, the above sql gets called.  If this produces an empty dataset, and I try to get the value of combo2, even though the list is empty, the value says it's 1

thanks

Comment: When you say *"Combo 2 uses this query"*, how does it use that query?  If it's the Row Source query for Combo 2 ... the query which fills the list is restricted by its current value(?) ... that seems wrong.

Comment: You can determine if there are any values in the comboBox by checking like: If Me.Combo2.ListCount = 0 then ..... But I agree with @HansUp that you can't be using Combo2 in your SQL - I think you mean Combo1.

Comment: Combo2 uses it as a rowsource.  The rowsource Type is Table/Query.  Yes, the query I posted has a type.  I will fix it.

Comment: There's another typo.. when you say "When it requeries, if the list is empty, and I do combobox1.value, instead of being null, the value is 1."  don't you really mean  to use COMBOBOX2.Value??? If ComboBox 1 is bound, it will probably always have a value...

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that.  You are correct, when I debug at combo1 Afterupdate I can see combo2.value = 1

Comment: The initial value of a bound combobox after a requery is always the value that is already in the dataset. Even if this is not in the List.

Comment: Johanness, that does seem correct.  If i do further testing and have the last combo2 value something other than 1, then change combo1 and requery, combo2.value will be that last selected value.  So, how do you overcome this?  It seems weird it would retain the last value before the requery

Comment: Nevermind, if I do this:  Me.Combo2.Value = Me.Combo2.ItemData(0) it seems to work.  thanks!

Comment: I posted this with additionla text as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requery requeries the List - not the value. The value stays whatever it is/was before. Its not a bug - its a feature ;-) 
If you page through datasets that are already filled you wouldn't want them to be changed without user interaction. The List is just a helper for dataEntry (and validation - if you check "only listitems allowed") - but it has nothing to do with your dataset. 
By setting the value to your first Entry like you proposed: `Me.Combo2.Value = Me.Combo2.ItemData(0)` you change the dataset intentionally. And that is how it is supposed to happen. Not via changing the list.